# Symfony 2.3 form is not validating Gregwar captcha code

Tags: php, symfony, captcha, symfony-forms

My template is showing image but after submission the form it shows always bad code error.
Any suggestion
My controller

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder()
    ->add('captcha', 'captcha')
    ->getForm();
$form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isValid()) {
    // some activity
} else {
    echo 'captcha error';
}
```

Comment: can you var_dump($form->getErrors()); before the isValid ?

Answer (score 0):

I met this issue too. And I resolve this by use a new action to handle the form submission, not use the same action that create the form and the captcha.

Maybe if you use the same action to create the form and handle the form submission, it will regenerate the captcha code when you submit the form, as the result the captcha field is stale and not validate still.